If a shop prices all items extremely high and applies a "non-criminal discount" at checkout, will shoplifters get prosecuted based on the high price?
I came across this sign online that states that in the store, all items are marked at $951, with "non-criminal discounts" applied only for paying customers. The sign suggests that this is to ensure that shoplifters will be prosecuted for grand theft under California Penal Code 487 PC, according to which the threshold for grand theft is $950.

I can't verify the post itself, but regardless - would this actually work? If a shoplifter were caught, could they be prosecuted based on the marked price of $951, even though noone actually has to pay that price, or would the actual price at checkout be considered in the prosecution?
While the sign itself is specific to California, I'm interested in different legal systems as well.
(I'm also interested if such pricing would be even legal in itself, but I want to limit my post to one question.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

california
No, I don't think so.
California's grand theft statute, Penal Code Section 487 (which you already linked) consistently uses the word "value" rather than "price" (emphasis mine):


Grand theft is theft committed in any of the following cases: (a) When the money, labor, real property, or personal property taken
is of a value exceeding nine hundred fifty dollars ($950), except as
provided in subdivision (b).


Earlier in that title, Section 484(a) says:

In determining the value of the property obtained, for the purposes of this section, the reasonable and fair market value shall be the test, and in determining the value of services received the contract price shall be the test.

(While technically this is not in the same section, the context seems to make it clear that this test of "value" was intended to apply to other sections in Title 13 as well, except in some specific instances where a different test is explicitly stated.)
So regardless of the sticker price of the goods, if the reasonable and fair market value of the goods is less than or equal to $950, grand theft has not been committed.  And the sign itself more or less admits that $951 is not the reasonable and fair market value, as no customer is expected to voluntarily pay that amount.
I did notice in Section 490.5, describing required restitution, includes:

In addition to the foregoing damages, the adult or emancipated minor shall be liable to the merchant for the retail value of the merchandise if it is not recovered in merchantable condition [...]

There might be a slightly stronger case to apply the $951 figure here.  But I'd expect that to fail as well, given that no retail customer is paying $951.

Wow, it seems like the law was written to specifically disallow the trick the sign is trying to establish.

@quarague - Not that single specific trick.  There are lots of methods to value an item and the law specifies one.

It's clearly a statement with no legal effect.  If all the items are marked $951 and you don't find out the real cost until you get to the register, there won't be many customers.  There'd have to be buy-in from corrupt cops and a corrupt prosecutor to try something so silly and it would never get by a judge.

canada
This sign would likely be ineffective at altering the charge or sentence.
Theft is defined in the Criminal Code at s. 322 and the offence is created at s. 334. The severity of the offence turns on whether the "value" of what is stolen is more than $5,000.
To prove theft over $5,000, the burden is on the Crown to prove the higher value beyond a reasonable doubt.
In the retail shoplifting context, courts have looked to what price the thing would typically sell at. See R. v. Wheeler, 2012 ABPC 127, para. 36 (relying on reasoning from the BC Court of Appeal):

In the context of the criminal law, as it relates to the theft of property, it would seem most appropriate that the value is determined by the monetary worth of the property to the owner.  In the context of a retail operation, this value would be the retail price, as the value is the price that a seller is willing to accept and a buyer is willing to pay on the open market in an arms length transaction.

In the scenario you describe, the Crown would have difficulty proving beyond a reasonable doubt that people were actually willing to pay $951 for the items.
Low-level shoplifting is "not considered a very serious offence" (R. v. Hackett, 2013 CanLII 80918 (NL PC), para. 24):

the usual range of sentence for shoplifting type theft offences includes discharges for first time offenders, fines, suspended sentences with probation (with a condition prohibiting the return of the offender to the premises where the theft was committed for a few months), or short and sharp periods of imprisonment where there is a prior related criminal record.

A store owner is not able to dictate a different approach by the use of signage.
Last, charge approval is an individualized exercise. The claim that "all shoplifters" will be prosecuted, whether under a given provision, or at all, would not reflect Crown charging policy.

australia
The business is committing an offence
It is unlawful for a business to engage in deceptive and misleading conduct in trade or commerce.
The sign unequivocally states “The state of California will prosecute …” which is factually wrong and deceptive and misleading — while the state may prosecute, it’s discretionary, so that doesn’t amount to will prosecute.
Also, at least in new-south-wales, all theft is grand larceny; Crimes Act 1900 s116:

Every larceny, whatever the value of the property stolen, shall be deemed to be of the same nature, and shall be subject to the same incidents in all respects, as grand larceny was before the passing of the Act seventh and eighth George the Fourth, chapter twenty-nine.


It's not illegal to make empty threats. People say "I'll sue you!" when they have no intention of really suing all the time. I remember at least once parking in "tow away" zone and not being towed. I don't think the business is committing any offense here by mere lying about what the state will or may do. This has nothing to do with commerce. One might argue that marking all prices at $951, but charging something else may be unlawful, but in California it only applies if the actual charge is higher than posted.

If I were a juror, I would assume that the sign was not intended to deceive anybody who wished to engage in "trade or commerce" with the shopkeeper.

@SolomonSlow intention is not relevant. Neither is harm. It is simply an objective question of if a reasonable person is likely to be misled or deceived. Indeed, strictly factual statements have been found to be misleading or deceptive in context.

The sign states "The state of California will prosecute..." while we're clearly in Australia! Deceptive and misleading....

@Eonema but I’m not in trade or commerce

@DaleM Does that mean that there virtually no alternative "medicine" practitioner in Australia considering pretty much all of them make factually wrong statements? Would the answer not be more appropriately started with "It could potentially be unlawful if a court considers the statement "The state of California will prosecute..." factually wrong enough to be deceptive or misleading"?

@YanickSalzmann of course not. They just can’t claim that it’s medicine. Or that it has any efficacy. You can sell Lilly water so long as you don’t claim it will do anything.

I think that the sign fails because of Australian consumer law, as well - if a store displays two different prices for an item, the lower price is applied as a matter of law and the business commits an offence if they charge the higher price.

I guess I could have said it better. "Intent" was not a key word in my mind. The key words were "trade or commerce." As a juror, I would opine that the sign would not deceive any person who enters the store for the purpose of engaging in trade or commerce.

@littleadv: So it's merely intellectual dishonesty then.

When someone who isn't law enforcement makes a claim about offenders being prosecuted, I think it's universally understood as meaning that they'll be reported to law enforcement. This is similar to signs that say "trespassers will be prosecuted."

But is the sign  unequivocally stating that the state of California will prosecute all shoplifters, or is it stating the all shoplifters prosecuted by the state of California will by prosecuted under CA penal code 487 PC Grand Theft?  To me it reads as the latter.  Further, this seems the more controversial part of the whole thing.

@Andy either way, it’s an unequivocal statement about what the business owner has no control over.

Does California have any law that requires posted prices to be accurate?
